# Create new android application project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I tried creating a new android application project in Eclipse (4.2 for Java) with latest android sdk as per http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html
I enter the application name and the project name. The other values are default.

After I click on finish on the final step, the window of creating a new project is still open.  I have to click on 'X' to close the window. In the project explore, the new project is created but all the icon in front of files are in grey and there is no src file.

Could anyone help please? Thanks!

Comment: Have you linked the SDK with Eclipse?

Comment: Do you have the last SDK? I had a similar problem with an old SDK and Indigo Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks both. After I update ADT, it could create new android projects now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your MainActivity.java in "src" folder is not created at all.
You'll need to update the ADT.

Go to following: 
*'Help'->'Install New Software'* and type 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select ADT option and install it.
It will update the ADT.

Even I had the same problem and my issue got resolved with it!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these things:

1. Java SDK Latest (or most popular, which is Java 7 at the moment even though 8 is available)
2. ADT
3. Eclipse is updated (via menu...Help > Check for Updates)
4. Check JDK Path

   - Via menu...Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > [Point to path]

     - path should be similar to this for

       - x64: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
       - x86: C:\Program Files x86\Java\jre7
       - x64[JDK]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
       - x86[JDK]: C:\Program Files x86\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
5. When creating Android projects in Eclipse Kepler use a minimum API of 14 because there seems to be a bug causing Eclipse Kepler to crash (Other related issues: [AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374891/unable-to-write-jarlist-cache-file-while-creating-android-project)! )