# Unable to write jarlist cache file while creating android project

Tags: android, android-appcompat

While creating an android project in Eclipse, I get the error:

`[2014-03-13 15:14:36 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Neelakanteshwar\AndroidFirst\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache`

And `appcompat_v7` folder is created along with project folder in Eclipse.

Can anyone please help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 30):

If you go to `appcompat_v7/bin` folder, you'll see that file `jarlist.cache` doesn´t appear or is unsynchronized. You need to refresh the `appcompat_v7` folder, only press F5 over that folder.

The `appcompat_v7` folder is added because you use an action bar component.

Aah. To avoid a new `appcompat_v7_XX` folder when you are creating a new project, **choose a LEVEL API 14 as Minimum Required SDK.**

After that, you must modifier the `AndroidManifest.xml` and put the level that you need.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"   ------> change it
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`
```

> **Heads up!** Delete all `appcompat_v7_XX`. It is a bug.

With `appcompat_v7`, you will see that Eclipse creates two XML files:

- `activity_main.xml`
- `fragment_main.xml`

If you want to have an option to create a project in the old way only with `activity_main.xml`, do that:

- Make a copy of the folder "BlanckActivity" located in this path: `\sdk\tools\templates\activities` of an ADT previous version.
- Rename the folder as `BlankActivityNoFragment`, then edit the field name of the file `template.xml` such that, it reads `name=BlankActivityNoFragment`
- Copy the new folder in the same path of the new Eclipse IDE: `sdk/tools/templates/activities`

Now you´ll see the new template when you go to create a new project.

**Remember to choose as Minimum Required SDK as API 14**

Comment: Refreshing worked but I just deleted both projects from disk and restarted the tutorial using minSDK level 14.  Thanks

Comment: Changed to level 14, cleaned all projects (`Project -> Clean...`) worked for me.

Comment: Or instead of changing minSdkVersion to 14 if you dont want to, just create your new project with the appropriate minSdkVersion, let the eclipse to create a new appcompat_v7_XX file but after all delete that file and change the libraries of your project! Great answer Necho

Answer (score 2):

Change Workspace path in starting Eclipse:

- from `C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\workspace`
- to, for example `D:\My_Folder`

Answer (score 2):

<del>Also got the same problem today.</del>

- Install and configure all the required components.
- On the **menu bar,** go to: `Project->Properties->Java build path`.
- On the **order and export** tab: check all the project libraries. I checked **Android 4.4.**

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the professional way but it worked for me.

- Manually create a folder named jar in the path: `C:\Users\\***\appcompat_v7\bin\`
- Referesh your project in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you also need Adroid Version 2.1!
Go to Android SDK Manager and download Android Version 2.1 (API 7)

If you start a new Android App. Project there is typed that FROM 2.1 TILL 4.4 Android version.
So that mean the program is searching for the minimum Android version bro :)

BTW: Download the 2.2. Android Version, too. :)

Comment: I installed both 2.1 and 2.2, but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Just got the same problem today.</del>

In my case the combination of your advices became a solution:

1. In Eclipse project bar I have deleted Appcompat(XYZ) and the new project that I just created.
2. Checked for updates - no updates were found.
3. Clicked File -> Restart.
4. While creating new project have chosen API 14 as Minimum Required SDK.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Run an Eclipse update (Help -> Check for Updates) and let me know if this resolves your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just refresh the bin folder of appcompat_v7!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
When create android-support-v7-appcompat, mark the option "Copy projects into workspace". Now, it can write in the required directories.
I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I met the same situation. I deleted my project from eclipse and on the disk, delete the workspace from the disk, and recreate the project in the new workspace... it works.......

Answer (score 0):

A different approach worked in my case, saying it here if it can help someone. I also came across this weird problem of `appcompat` while creating a new project.

I have just **clean and build** the default `appcompat_v7` project for **2 times** which is created by eclipse itself and voila it worked! and all errors are gone, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and the following steps worked for me.

Just delete the `gen` and `bin` folders

Clean(Re build) the project.

Answer (score -1):

```
Here is *Simple Trick:*

 Create New Project

 If you get the warning of jarlist Not created under the console tab

 Close Eclipse and ReOpen it

Now u r done. jarlist is included in appcompat_7/bin or appcompat_7_XX/bin
```