# Using 1.7 requires using Android Build Tools version 19 or later

Tags: android, sdk, adt, google-play-services

Yesterday I was updating Google Play Service on ADT and this morning I have an exclamation icon on my project and this errors:
Can anyone help me please?

> [2014-06-16 10:31:53 - google-play-services_lib] WARNING: unable to
> write jarlist cache file
> C:\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\jarlist.cache
>
> [2014-06-16 10:35:48 - google-play-services_lib] Using 1.7 requires
> using Android Build Tools version 19 or later; currently using 18.0.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374891/unable-to-write-jarlist-cache-file-while-creating-android-project

Comment: I have been searching on stack overflow , but I didn't find nothing, maybe I was using not correct words. thanks @Opiatefuchs

Comment: @Demetria Have you added app compat library in your project?

Comment: no problem...hope it helps :) ....

Comment: @pratik . No I have not. But right now if I make right click on my project and I go to properties I can see appcompat_v7_2 as library. Strange O_o I not using it , and yesterday It was not there.

Comment: OOpppsss!!! can you please send me your code?? let me check it in my editor.

Comment: Sorry I was ckecking my first test project! All is fine right now :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Download latest ADT from here then install it, your problem will be solved. As you have the older version of ADT (18.0.1).

[ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: The Android Build Tools are part of the Android SDK Manager, so you don't need to reinstall ADT. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to update your Android Build Tools to a later version. Unfortunately like a lot of things in the Android SDK it's not obvious how exactly you do this.

- Open the Android SDK Manager
- Under Tools, tick "Android SDK Build Tools 20" (or whatever the newest version is
- Click Install Packages
- Restart Eclipse

Comment: From the menubar: Window->Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Yes, that is how you open the Android SDK Manager, and that bit should hopefully be obvious to anyone who has used Eclipse for Android development.