# Another Unable to write jarlist cache file while creating android project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Actually I wanted to ask this in a comment to an existing post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374891/unable-to-write-jarlist-cache-file-while-creating-android-project) but as a newbie I don't have the required reputation... So here it is: After trying few suggestions that didn't work (keep getting "unable to write jarlist" etc.), I'm not sure how to proceed. The only thing that did work was to set minSdkVersion to 14 on project creation and thus a new appcompat lib is not created, but what if I want my app to be valid for API level 8 devices and up?

Comment: Hey guys, surely there is some solution, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just refresh your project explorer use f5
or do clean all project
go to Project menu then go to clean and tick clean all project then click ok

Comment: Actually I had settled with minSdkVersion 14. Yet, I do remember that I tried cleaning and it didn't help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tried to reopen your eclipse or your project. In my pc that's fix my problem.Or just reinstall your adt. hope your problem solved

Comment: Thanks, but as I realized that I'm OK with 14 I didn't continue with this struggle :-)