# Android Exclamatory red mark

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I'm very new to Android. Whenever I create a new project using a new workspace, I get an exclamatory red mark in Eclipse in my project and an error at `Appcompat`. I searched here for an answer, but no answer was what I was looking for, so I just asked this. When I create a workspace at DDMS it displays this:

```
Sending Tracking request failed!
```

At Android, after I create a new project

```
WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file here, src file, layout file not available.
```

I've searched a lot and found no solution.

Comment: actually its startup error. i cant create new project is my problem. when i create new project it shows exclamatory red mark and there is no src -> .java file and layout .xml file.

Comment: If you are new to Android you should be using Android Studio rather than Eclipse as Google are dropping support for development using Eclipse.

Comment: May be this post can help you out [Link to post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22209435/2412582)

Comment: What is your reason for using Eclipse? You are new to Android development so it seems like you are just trying to learn Android. Is it for a job that requires Eclipse? What is your reasoning?

Comment: yes, I m new to android. For job i need to work and basically team required eclipse working person. If possible kindly tell me solution for above problem than giving advice to shift studio...

Comment: @UserAndroid It didn't seem like Eclipse was 100% required in your case as you just said you were new to Android development. Since you said otherwise, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, first thing first. Eclipse is no longer supported by Google. The only official IDE for Android Development is [`Android Studio`](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) [Download Page](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Here is the [announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) of Eclipse support ending

> Over the past few years, our team has focused on improving the development experience for building Android apps with Android Studio. Since the launch of Android Studio, we have been impressed with the excitement and positive feedback. As the official Android IDE, Android Studio gives you access to a powerful and comprehensive suite of tools to evolve your app across Android platforms, whether it's on the phone, wrist, car or TV.
>
> **To that end and to focus all of our efforts on making Android Studio better and faster, we are ending development and official support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse at the end of the year. This specifically includes the Eclipse ADT plugin and Android Ant build system.**

Please note that the number of people using Eclipse to develop Android apps are going down. You will get less and less support even on Stackoverflow as time goes by. Overall, it is better to just make the switch while you are just starting.

Check on the first link, you will see some amazing documentation in the `Android Studio IDE`

---

### If you 100% required to use Eclipse...

OK, so you have a job that requires Eclipse or there is some other reason, then check out [this documentation by Eclipse](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part2.html#JavaViews).

Also, here is a [list of all the different icons](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) that can be displayed by Eclipse ([credit for the icon list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31987790/2333021)).

> Build path problems are sometimes easy to miss among other problems in a project. The Package Explorer and Project Explorer views now show a new decorator on Java projects and working sets that contain build path errors:

[image]

> The concrete errors can be seen in the Problems view, and if you open the view menu and select Group By > Java Problem Type, they all show up in the Build Path category:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting any problem with app_compact library... This is the solution

Hopefully it will work....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374891/unable-to-write-jarlist-cache-file-while-creating-android-project)

> > If you go to appcompat_v7/bin folder, you'll see that file "jarlist.cache" doesn´t appear or is unsynchronized. You need to
> >     refresh the appcompat_v7 folder, only press F5 over that folder.
>
> The appcompat_v7 folder is added because you use an action bar
>   component.
>
> Aah. To avoid a new appcompat_v7_XX folder when you are creating a new
>   project, choose a LEVEL API 14 as Minimun Required SDK. After you must
>   modifier the AndroidManifest.xml and put the level that you need.
>
> change it
>           android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
>
> Delete all appcompat_v7_XX. It is a bug.
>
> With appcompat_v7, You will see that Eclipse creates two XML files:
>   Activity_main.xml and fragment_main.xml. If you want to have an option
>   to create a project in the old way only with activity_main.xml, do
>   that:
>
> Make a copy of the folder "BlanckActivity" located in this path:
>   \sdk\tools\templates\activities of an ADT previous version.
>
> Rename the folder as “BlankActivityNoFragment”, then edit the field
>   name of the file "template.xml" with a notepad as
>   name=”BlankActivityNoFragment”
>
> Copy the new folder in the same path of the new Eclipse
>   IDE:sdk/tools/templates/activities
>
> Now you´ll see the new template when you go to create a new project.
>   Remember to choose as Minimum Required SDK an API 14

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the support of appcompat library then just remove it from your project by following steps :

1. Right click on project
2. Select properties
3. In dialog select android on left side
4. In dialog check library section
5. Remove appcompat library by selecting it and press remove
6. Extends your MainActivity.java with Activity

You can run your project successfully.

If you want the support of appcompat then follow this steps :

1. download the latest appcompat using Sdk Manager
2. import appcompat project in your eclipse
3. add it as a library project
4. extend your MainActivity with AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

> Decorates Java projects and working sets that contain build path
>   errors

There can be several reasons. Most of the times it may be some of the below reasons ,

1. You have deleted some of the .jar files from your /lib folder
2. You have added new .jar files
3. you have added new .jar files which may be conflict with others

So what to do is we have to resolve those missing / updating / newly_added jar files.

- right click on the project and go to properties
- Select Java Build Path
- go to the Libraries tab
- Remove the references of the jar files which you have removed already. There will be a red mark near them so you can identify them easily.
- Add the references to the newly added .jar files by using Add JARs Refresh the project

This will solve the problem if it's because one of the above reasons.

Still Facing problem ??Try this:

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Build and uncheck "Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch" then restart Eclipse.