# Eclipse Android Helloworld Blank

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to android. I had this issue [Unable to write jarlist cache file while creating android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374891/unable-to-write-jarlist-cache-file-while-creating-android-project) then I just hit F5 on both appcompat_V7 and HelloWorld folders to get rid of it. But still the helloWolrd project is bugging. I just followed this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm
I did not do anything but following the tutorial (IDE settings and Hello world projct) What's going on ?Could you help me fix the issue ? Below is a picture of what Eclipse looks like afet hitting F5 on on both appcompat_V7 and HelloWorld folders
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google dropped support for Eclipse Android Developer Tools back in June 2015 so you might find inconsistencies with that IDE.

The Android developers blog is quite clear as to why:

> To that end and to focus all of our efforts on making Android Studio better and faster, we are ending development and official support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse at the end of the year. This specifically includes the Eclipse ADT plugin and Android Ant build system.

The official blog post can be found [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html).

I believe that continuing to develop in Eclipse will result in further errors the more you will progress.

My suggestion is to start your development using the official Android Studio IDE which you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html).

Comment: Did not knowabout that. Anyways I dropped Android studio because I could not fin simple tutorials like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android  Any idea here ? Plus I'm having so many bug just after following http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html   It's kinda frustrating

Comment: @KurtMiller I can relate to the initial frustration, I felt the same way at the beginning. Personally I followed a YouTube channel in my first steps called [slidenerd](https://www.youtube.com/user/slidenerd) that has a ton of nicely made videos about developing Android and with Android Studio

Comment: oops sorry. My bad